# NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I am playing around scopes in rails model.

These queries works perfectly in development environment but not production.

Here is my `Fee` model from where I am triggering `active-record` query to get specific invoices from `StudentFeeInvoice` Model.

**app/models/fee.rb**

```
most_recent_invoice = aStudent.student_fee_invoices.invoices_except_pending_and_adjusted.order(:created_at).last
new_filter_for_invoices = aStudent.student_fee_invoices.invoices_after_specific_date(most_recent_invoice.created_at)"
```

**app/model/student_fee_invoice.rb**

```
scope :invoices_except_pending_and_adjusted, -> {where("status != ? AND status != ?", "Pending", "Adjusted")}
scope :invoices_after_specific_date, -> (created_date) {where('created_at > ?', created_date)}
```

please correct me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would love to explain  if someone asks for context to explain furthermore to build understanding.

Answer (score 1):

most probably, `aStudent.student_fee_invoices.invoices_except_pending_and_adjusted.order(:created_at).last`
is returning `nil`

In that case you'll need something like:

```
new_filter_for_invoices = aStudent.student_fee_invoices.invoices_after_specific_date(most_recent_invoice ? most_recent_invoce.created_at : DateTime.now)
```

Comment: Love you @Roc Khalil ...!

Comment: You avoided error & transferred date to `DateTime.now` but are you sure will this date make sense for his further logic implementation ?

Comment: Actually I am using new_filter_for_invoices as a flag if its "0" I want next code of block not to be executed. so what about this new_filter_for_invoices = aStudent.student_fee_invoices.invoices_after_specific_date(most_recent_invoice.created_at)" if new_filter_for_invoices.present?